# INNER JOIN in UPDATE sql for DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to use joins in update statements for DB2?

Google has really let me down on this one

This is roughly what I'm trying to achieve (... except obviously working ....)

```
update file1 inner join file2                                 
       on substr(file1.firstfield,10,20) = substr(file2.anotherfield,1,10)                                                                    
set file1.firstfield = ( 'BIT OF TEXT' concat file2.something )                                                                             
where file1.firstfield like 'BLAH%'
```

Cheers

Answer (score 9):

Joins in `update` statements are non-standard and not supported by all vendors.  What you're trying to do can be accomplished with a sub-select:

```
update
  file1
set
  firstfield = (select 'stuff' concat something from file2 where substr(file1.field1, 10, 20) = substr(file2.xxx,1,10) )
where
  file1.foo like 'BLAH%'
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't say what platform you're targeting.  Referring to tables as files, though, leads me to believe that you're NOT running DB2 on Linux, UNIX or Windows (LUW).

However, if you *are* on DB2 LUW, see the [MERGE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) statement:
**update: note that Db2 for IBM i added `MERGE` support in late 2010 to v7.1 and higher.  Db2 for z/OS also has it.**

For your example statement, this would be written as:

```
merge into file1 a
   using (select anotherfield, something from file2) b
   on substr(a.firstfield,10,20) = substr(b.anotherfield,1,10)
when matched and a.firstfield like 'BLAH%'
   then update set a.firstfield = 'BIT OF TEXT' || b.something;
```

Please note:  For DB2, the third argument of the SUBSTR function is the number of bytes to return, not the ending position.  Therefore, SUBSTR(a.firstfield,10,20) returns CHAR(20).  However, SUBSTR(b.anotherfield,1,10) returns CHAR(10).  I'm not sure if this was done on purpose, but it may affect your comparison.

Comment: Interesting catch on the use of "file", which is commonly used interchangeably with "table" among developers using IBM i.  In this OS, a DB2 table is an externally described physical database file.  However, an executable program object is not a file.

Comment: I like the point that you used columns and not entire table

Answer (score 7):

Try this and then tell me the results:

```
UPDATE File1 AS B                          
SET    b.campo1 = (SELECT DISTINCT A.campo1
                   FROM  File2 A           
                   INNER JOIN File1      
                   ON A.campo2 = File1.campo2 
                   AND A.campo2 = B.campo2)
```

Comment: I don't knwo if you noticed, but the OP was last seen her Jan 24 2011 at 13:03.  it is unlikely he/she will be back.

Comment: @Linger True, but answers are still found by searchers years later. If an answer is valid, it can always be relevant.

Answer (score 6):

Update to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4184237/565525:

if you want **multiple columns**, that can be achived like this:

```
update file1
set
  (firstfield, secondfield) = (
        select 'stuff' concat 'something from file2', 
               'some secondfield value' 
        from file2
        where substr(file1.field1, 10, 20) = substr(file2.xxx,1,10) )
where
  file1.foo like 'BLAH%'
```

Source: http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1615011-sql-update-using-join-subquery.html#post6257307

Answer (score 5):

Here's a good example of something I just got working:

```
update cac c
set ga_meth_id = (
    select cim.ga_meth_id 
    from cci ci, ccim cim 
    where ci.cus_id_key_n = cim.cus_id_key_n
    and ci.cus_set_c = cim.cus_set_c
    and ci.cus_set_c = c.cus_set_c
    and ci.cps_key_n = c.cps_key_n
)
where exists (
    select 1  
    from cci ci2, ccim cim2 
    where ci2.cus_id_key_n = cim2.cus_id_key_n
    and ci2.cus_set_c = cim2.cus_set_c
    and ci2.cus_set_c = c.cus_set_c
    and ci2.cps_key_n = c.cps_key_n
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to update only the rows that match the conditions, and avoid updating nulls in the other rows:

```
update table_one set field_1 = 'ACTIVE' where exists 
(select 1 from table_two where table_one.customer = table_two.customer);
```

It works  in a DB2/AIX64 9.7.8

Comment: Thanks! you solved my problem. (DB2 v11.1.4.4)

update [schema].TableA 
set 
    Column1 = 'Foo',
    Column2 = 'Bar'
where exists
(
    select 
        1
    from [schema].TableB
 where
     [schema].TableB.CommonColumn=[schema].TableA.CommonColumn
        and [schema].TableB.key = 'condition'
);

I haven't used that syntax before, but strangely it works much better than a join.

Answer (score 1):

for you ask

```
update file1 f1
set file1.firstfield=
(
select 'BIT OF TEXT' || f2.something
from file2 f2
where substr(f1.firstfield,10,20) = substr(f2.anotherfield,1,10)
)
where exists
(
select * from file2 f2
where substr(f1.firstfield,10,20) = substr(f2.anotherfield,1,10)
)
and f1.firstfield like 'BLAH%'
```

if join give multiple result you can force update like this

```
update file1 f1
set file1.firstfield=
(
select 'BIT OF TEXT' || f2.something
from file2 f2
where substr(f1.firstfield,10,20) = substr(f2.anotherfield,1,10)
fetch first rows only
)
where exists
(
select * from file2 f2
where substr(f1.firstfield,10,20) = substr(f2.anotherfield,1,10)
)
and f1.firstfield like 'BLAH%'
```

template methode

```
update table1 f1
set (f1.field1, f1.field2, f1.field3, f1.field4)=
(
select f2.field1, f2.field2, f2.field3, 'CONSTVALUE'
from table2 f2
where (f1.key1, f1.key2)=(f2.key1, f2.key2) 
)
where exists 
(
select * from table2 f2
where (f1.key1, f1.key2)=(f2.key1, f2.key2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference documentation for [the UPDATE statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001022.html) on DB2 LUW 9.7 gives the following example:

```
   UPDATE (SELECT EMPNO, SALARY, COMM,
     AVG(SALARY) OVER (PARTITION BY WORKDEPT),
     AVG(COMM) OVER (PARTITION BY WORKDEPT)
     FROM EMPLOYEE E) AS E(EMPNO, SALARY, COMM, AVGSAL, AVGCOMM)
   SET (SALARY, COMM) = (AVGSAL, AVGCOMM)
   WHERE EMPNO = '000120'
```

The parentheses after UPDATE can contain a full-select, meaning any valid SELECT statement can go there.

Based on that, I would suggest the following:

```
UPDATE (
  SELECT
    f1.firstfield,
    f2.anotherfield,
    f2.something
  FROM file1 f1
  WHERE f1.firstfield like 'BLAH%' 
  INNER JOIN file2 f2
  ON substr(f1.firstfield,10,20) = substr(f2.anotherfield,1,10)
)
AS my_files(firstfield, anotherfield, something)
SET
  firstfield = ( 'BIT OF TEXT' || something )
```

Edit: Ian is right. My first instinct was to try subselects instead:

```
UPDATE file1 f1
SET f1.firstfield = ( 'BIT OF TEXT' || (
  SELECT f2.something
  FROM file2 f2
  WHERE substr(f1.firstfield,10,20) = substr(f2.anotherfield,1,10)
))
WHERE f1.firstfield LIKE 'BLAH%' 
AND substr(f1.firstfield,10,20) IN (
  SELECT substr(f2.anotherfield,1,10)
  FROM file2 f2
)
```

But I'm not sure if the concatenation would work. It also assumes that there's a 1:1 mapping between the substrings. If there are multiple rows that match, it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can't update a fullselect that contains a join -- just like you can't update a view that contains a join (without an INSTEAD OF trigger).  This statement will return SQL01050N.

Answer (score 0):

On DB2 it's like that :

```
UPDATE TABLE
set TABLE.firstfield = ( 'BIT OF TEXT' concat TABLE.something )                                                                             
where TABLE.firstfield like 'BLAH%'
```

Comment: how does it address the question "Is there a way to use **joins** in update statements"?

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE tes_1  a
SET a.nama = 
(SELECT b.nama FROM tes_2 b WHERE a.urut = b.urut )
```

Comment: how does it address the question "Is there a way to use **joins** in update statements"?

Answer (score -3):

In standard SQL this type of update looks like:

```
update a
   set a.firstfield ='BIT OF TEXT' + b.something
  from file1 a
  join file2 b
    on substr(a.firstfield,10,20) = 
       substr(b.anotherfield,1,10)
 where a.firstfield like 'BLAH%'
```

With minor syntactic variations this type of thing will work on Oracle or SQL Server and (although I don't have a DB/2 instance to hand to test) will almost certainly work on DB/2.

Comment: Thanks ConcernedOfTunbridge - unfortunately this doesnt work in DB2, I get an error saying "Column qualifier or table B undefined"

Comment: have you tried || instead of +, and you want to type inner join instead of 'join' - I think the substr function should be '10, 10' not '10, 20' see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000854.htm

Comment: Standard SQL doesn't support JOINs in UPDATE statements...  That's SQL Server syntax; MySQL supports JOINS in UPDATE statements, but not with that syntax.