# Repeating Subquery in DB2 update

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, updates

I am currently creating an update statement which will update a bitemporal table. It does the following:

Update every Row for every ID and set the RELATION_ID to the RELATION_ID of the newest row.

In this query, there is a repeating subquery ( Because I first use it to get the value used to update) and also ( I don't want to update rows which already have this RELATION_ID)

Is there a way to reuse the value from the first query or any alternatives?(Without programming, pure SQL required)

```
UPDATE TBL_CLIENT UPD
SET RELATION_ID = (
                  SELECT RELATION_ID FROM TBL_CLIENT SUBQ
                  WHERE  UPD.ID = SUBQ.ID AND
                         UPDATE_TIMESTAMP =    (
                                            SELECT MAX(UPDATE_TIMESTAMP) FROM TBL_CLIENT SUBSQ
                                            WHERE  SUBSQ.ID = SUBQ.ID
                                           )
                 )               
WHERE ID IN  ( 
                    SELECT ID
                    FROM TBL_CLIENT QU
                    GROUP BY ID
                    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(RELATION_ID)) > 1
                   ) AND         
      RELATION_ID <> (
                        SELECT RELATION_ID FROM TBL_CLIENT SUBQ2
                        WHERE  UPD.ID = SUBQ2.ID AND
                               UPDATE_TIMESTAMP =    (
                                                  -- Update mit STID des neusten Eintrages
                                                  SELECT MAX(UPDATE_TIMESTAMP) FROM TBL_CLIENT SUBSQ2
                                                  WHERE  SUBSQ2.ID = SUBQ2.ID
                                                 )
                      )
```

Example:

ID / RELATION_ID / UPDATE_TIMESTAMP

- 1  / 10  / 1.1.2000
- 1  / 12  / 5.1.2002
- 1  / 15  / 28.3.2008

After Update:

- 1  / 15  / 1.1.2000
- 1  / 15  / 5.1.2002
- 1  / 15  / 28.3.2008

The last row was the most recent row, therefore it's relation id was taken (and the row itself wasn't updated!, important for an other part of the query which isn't included here)

Thanks for any recommendations

Comment: The advice is to replace the `update` with a `merge` . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184209/inner-join-in-update-sql-for-db2.

Comment: What is the Primary Key of the table?

Comment: The primary key consists of multible elements including the ID, the timestamp but not the Relation_Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update a view:

```
UPDATE 
  ( SELECT t.id, t.update_timestamp, ...      --- all the PK columns
           t.relation_id, 
           m.relation_id AS new_relation_id
    FROM 
        TBL_CLIENT AS t
      JOIN
        ( SELECT id, relation_id,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                    ORDER BY update_timestamp DESC)
                   AS rn
          FROM TBL_CLIENT
        ) AS m
        ON  m.id = t.id
    WHERE m.rn = 1
      AND m.relation_id <> t.relation_id
  ) AS upd
SET 
    relation_id = new_relation_id ;
```

Comment: Changing your JOIN with my part for the max tsd, the select returns all values I need, but I don't get it to work as an update :/

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, DB2 uses version 910, tried including the PK but the error persists (An unexpected token "(" was found ..... )

Comment: The exact msg: Lookup Error - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "(" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "<IDENTIFIER> STATISTICS".    Btw. I found http://goo.gl/osclj working, should accomplish the task... but I still wonder how to get this VIEW Updatable

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you-(I dont know the exact syntax. i work on sybase, so this is as per sybase)

```
UPDATE TBL_CLIENT AA
    SET RELATION_ID = BB.RELATION_ID
FROM
   TBL_CLIENT AA,
   TBL_CLIENT BB
WHERE
   AA.ID=BB.ID
   AND BB.UPDATE_TIMESTAMP=(SELECT MAX(UPDATE_TIMESTAMP) FROM TBL_CLIENT CC WHERE CC.ID=BB.ID)
```

Comment: or give the sample data and the expected output you want

Comment: Actually, it's not possible to define more than one table in an update in DB2, the FROM statement doesn't exist there, would be a good solution if it would be possible. Will update my post with a little example

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can use a trigger with an after/before update.