# How to update multiple matching records with data from another table

Tags: sql, merge, group-by, db2

Working with DB2 but guess this applies to SQL in general.

I have two tables; Table1 contains data where the Fix column could be same in multiple rows. Table2 has unique rows and has data I want to add to columns in the first table if one or more matches between the Fix column in Table1 and the Title column in Table2 are found.

I'm getting an issue in that the SQL is returning an error saying: "The same row of target table "xxxxxxx" was identified more than once for an update, delete or insert operation of the MERGE statement.."

Now that is expected ie I know there are multiple rows in the target table that match the criteria and need to have the data from the source table applied to them.

I'm using MERGE but is that just not going to be possible? Been looking at GROUP BY too but can't get it to work.

If I was doing this in another language I'd go through the source table, build a collection of matching records from the source then iterate through the collection updating that with the source data that needed adding. Thinking there is a more efficient way in SQL though?

This code is completely wrong (and returns the error above) but adding it here to help any good person who wants to lend a hand :-)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_RawData_With_xKey_Data ()
P1: BEGIN

MERGE INTO table1 AS T
USING table2 AS S
ON (T.FIX = S.TITLE) 

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    T.Rating = S.Rating, 
    T.GSDS = S.GSDS_Date, 
ELSE IGNORE ;


END P1
```

Comment: Read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184209/inner-join-in-update-sql-for-db2

Comment: What are the key's for table1 and table2?

Comment: please show us your table definitions (the primary key and the constraint columns will suffice)