# Update rows in DB2 using another table

Tags: db2

I would like to update a table by join. My query is

```
UPDATE 
XCTLG_ENTRY_OPERTNL_CMPGN_CALNDR 
INNER 
JOIN CATENTRY
ON CATENTRY.CATENTRY_ID = XCTLG_ENTRY_OPERTNL_CMPGN_CALNDR.CATENTRY_ID
SET 
XCTLG_ENTRY_OPERTNL_CMPGN_CALNDR.MOC_OUT_IND = 'N',
        XCTLG_ENTRY_OPERTNL_CMPGN_CALNDR.LAST_UPDT_USER_ID = 'rodmarco',
        XCTLG_ENTRY_OPERTNL_CMPGN_CALNDR.LAST_UPDT_TS = to_date('2016-01-13 00:00:00.000000','YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(CATENTRY.CATENTTYPE_ID)) = 'ProductBean'        
    AND CATENTRY.PARTNUMBER = 10195
    AND XCTLG_ENTRY_OPERTNL_CMPGN_CALNDR.CMPGN_YR_NR = 2016
    AND XCTLG_ENTRY_OPERTNL_CMPGN_CALNDR.CMPGN_NR = 18
```

The error which i got is

> Error code -104, SQL state 42601: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104,
>   SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=JOIN;;FROM, DRIVER=4.16.53

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=db2%20join%20update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN in UPDATE sql for DB2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184209/inner-join-in-update-sql-for-db2)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285136/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match-in-db2