# Update table from anothe table in DB2 is not working

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I am trying to update a postalcode of address from postalcode of historyaddress table.

```
UPDATE r 
   SET r.postalcode=h.postalcode 
FROM db2inst1.address r 
   INNER JOIN db2inst1.historyaddress h ON r.idno = h.idno AND r.addresscode = h.addresscode 
where '0' CONCAT r.postalcode=h.postalcode 
  and SUBSTR(r.postalcode,1,1)<>'0';
```

I would like to achive this. If postalcode(address table) contains 12345 and postalcode(historyaddress table) 012345, then replace postalcode(address table)
with 012345(which is in historyaddress table)

I am getting the below error.

"AGDB2.R" is an undefined name. SQL Code: -204, SQL State: 42704

Comment: Incorrect syntax.  Try UPDATE r SET .. = (SELECT ... FROM ... )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN in UPDATE sql for DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184209/inner-join-in-update-sql-for-db2)