# Update table based on criteria from a second table

Tags: db2, sql-update

I am trying to update one table based on  selection  criteria from  another table.  My SQL is

```
update
  hshed
set
  oaeiin = 'Y',
  OAEIND = '170201'
from
  hshed
  join cusms on oacono = cmcono
  and oacsno = cmcsno
where
  cmtpid like 'OB10%'
  and oainvd > 180120
  and oaeiin = 'N'
```

However, I  am getting an error that

```
 Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH WHERE.
```

I am not sure how to update a table based on criteria from a second table,  or how to use joins.  This is using  SQL in a DB2 database.

I have tried searching for a solution with no success.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that DB2 does not support the update join syntax you are using.  One possible workaround might be to use `EXISTS` clauses to handle the same logic you intend:

```
UPDATE
    hshed
SET
    oaeiin = 'Y',
    OAEIND = '170201'
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cusms WHERE oacono = cmcono) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cusms WHERE oacsno = cmcsno) AND
    cmtpid LIKE 'OB10%' AND
    oainvd > 180120 AND
    oaeiin = 'N';
```

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184209/inner-join-in-update-sql-for-db2) to a good Stack Overflow question discussing this problem in general.

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up just using my where to identify a list, and using the list in the update :)  Appreciate the help.