# Update with inner joins in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to perform an update on a db2 database with inner joins but it says the where clause is not expected. I'm simply trying to set a value based on another table's value with these conditions met (in the joins)

It seems as though joins are not allowed in DB2 updates?

What would be the proper way to perform this?

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS.SKUS SK
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS.BODY BD
ON SK.BODY_ID = BD.ID 
INNER JOIN LEGACY_SCHEMA.BODY_OLD BDC
ON BD.BODY_CODE = BDC.BODYF 
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS.CATEGORIES PC
ON BDC.CATEGORY_IDENTIFIER = PC.CATEGORY_SHORT 
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS.PARENTS PR
ON PR.ID = BD.PARENT_ID
SET SK.CATEGORY_ID = PC.ID
WHERE PR.PARENT_CODE IN (123)
LIMIT 8;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INNER JOIN in UPDATE sql for DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184209/inner-join-in-update-sql-for-db2)

Answer (score 0):

Use merge into sql command. Link https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=language-merging-data